# JavaScript - get reader.result outside of onload

Tags: javascript, io, filereader

The code below is what I have currently. I want to alert(reader.result) outside of onload, but it always returns null. Shouldn't reader.result keep its result after readAsText() is called **and finishes?**

To be more specific, my final goal is to read the text within files and then save it in a variable for future use. I've just been using alerts as debugging tools (probably bad, I know).

```
<input type="file" id="fileinput" />
<script type = "text/javascript" id="00">
    var contents = [];
    function readAFile(evt)
    {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var test
        var file = evt.target.files[0];

        if (file)
        {

            reader.onload = function (element) {
                alert("in onload");
                this.result = element.target.result;
                alert(reader.result);
            };
            reader.onerror = function (element) {
                alert("reader.onerror called - could not load");
            };

            reader.readAsText(file);
            alert(reader.result);

        }
        else
        {
            alert("if(file) returned false - could not load");
        }

    }

    document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readAFile, false);
```

Comment: FileReader is asynchronous. So you're calling `alert()` before it has read anything.

Comment: @Barmar That's what I thought at first, but the alert(reader.result) that is returning null pops up after the alert(reader.result) inside onload (which is returning the actual result). As I understand, alerts are synchronous, so that confirms that reading has finished in time.

Comment: I get the empty alert first in Chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/PkGH4/1/

Comment: @Barmer Yeah, same here. What's the best way of delaying until onload is finished running?

Comment: Do whatever you want in the onload handler, that's the point of it. Just like AJAX -- when you initiate an asynchronous action, use its callback to wait for it to complete.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<input type="file" id="files" name="file" />
<div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 500px"></div>

<script>
function handleFileSelect(evt)
{
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++)
    {

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function(reader)
        {
            return function()
            {
                var contents = reader.result;
                var lines = contents.split('\n');
                //////
                document.getElementById('container').innerHTML=contents;
            }
        })(reader);

        reader.readAsText(f);
    }
}
  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
</html>
```